# JavaFX Tab Text and Size Issues

Tags: css, javafx, tabs

Currently having a couple issues with JavaFX and CSS stylesheets. I would like to have the selected tab text to be black, and have the non selected tabs to be white. I was able to achieve the background color of the active tab being a darker blue than the rest, but still have an awkward area around the tabs.

Here is the app when it first opens:
First Open
[image]

Here is the app when I click on a tab:
First Click
[image]

On the second image the text gets completely lost in the background color. If you could help me get rid of the space around the tabs themselves as well that would be awesome too!

Here is my CSS file:

```css
/*main.css*/

/*set individual tab properties*/
.tab {
    -fx-background-color: #1c6fb8;
    -fx-font: 16px "Helvetica Neue" ;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
}

.tab-label {
    -fx-text-fill: #fff;
}

.tab:focused .tab-label {
    -fx-text-fill: #000;
}

.tab-header-background {
    -fx-background-color: #1c6fb8;
}

.tab-pane {
    -fx-tab-min-width:120px;
    -fx-tab-max-width:120px;
    -fx-tab-min-height:50px;
    -fx-tab-max-height:50px;
    -fx-background-color: #15558c;
}

.tab:selected {
    -fx-text-fill: #000;
    -fx-background-color: #15558c;
}

.tab-pane:focused > .tab-header-area > .headers-region > .tab:selected .focus-indicator {
    -fx-background-color: #15558c;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Key code:

```
.tab-pane .tab:selected
{
    -fx-background-color: #15558c;
}

.tab:selected .tab-label 
{ 
    -fx-text-fill: #000;
    -fx-background-color: #15558c;
}
```

> Full code:

```
.tab {
    -fx-background-color: #1c6fb8;
    -fx-font: 16px "Helvetica Neue" ;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
}

.tab-label {
    -fx-text-fill: #fff;
}

.tab:focused .tab-label {
    -fx-text-fill: #000;
}

.tab-header-background {
    -fx-background-color: #1c6fb8;
}

.tab-pane {
    -fx-tab-min-width:120px;
    -fx-tab-max-width:120px;
    -fx-tab-min-height:50px;
    -fx-tab-max-height:50px;
    -fx-background-color: #15558c;
}

/*.tab:selected {
    -fx-text-fill: #000;
    -fx-background-color: #15558c;
}*/

.tab-pane .tab:selected
{
    -fx-background-color: #15558c;
}

.tab:selected .tab-label { 
    -fx-text-fill: #000;
    -fx-background-color: #15558c;
}
```

> First Open:

[image: First Open]

> First Click:

[image]